# Создание объекта при помощи Instantiate в update в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру, столкнулся с проблемой - мне нужно, чтобы объект создался всего один раз при помощи instantiate в void Update. Пробовал использовать bool, но не получилось. Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты провернуть это без bool?

Comment: А зачем в Update? Серьезно! У вас что, бесконечные ресурсы, чтобы каждый кадр устраивать лишнюю проверку, которая всегда (кроме самого первого кадра) дает false. К тому же выполнение Update начинается вместе с Start! Так почему бы не сделать одиночное действие в Start. А если в Start нельзя, то опишите почему. Но выполнять в Update одиночное действие - это преступление против природы.

Comment: Единоразовые вещи не для `Update`. Хоть опишите условия на событиe для `Instantinate`.

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать, чтобы машина при начале игры если заезжаешь в триггер отключалась, начиналась анимация(не связанная с машиной) и после этого опять включалась, но после этого канвас перестает работать, поэтому решил перед анимацией уничтожать машину, а потом создавать заново, но когда она создаётся заново, то машины клонируются, а singleplayer дает создавать объект один раз, так что он не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем это делать именно в `Update()` мне не понятно, но можно сделать так:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _objectTemplate;
private bool _templateIsSpawned;

private void Update () {
    if (_templateIsSpawned == false) {
        Instantiate(_objectTemplate);
        _templateIsSpawned = true;
    } 
}
```

Вешать скрипт нужно не на тот объект, который хочешь создать, а на другой объект на сцене

Comment: А зачем его нормализировать?